# Add 1 int per frame but resulting random number on the last frame

Tags: actionscript-3, integer

i am in the middle of making interactive multimedia learning and as today i am working on quiz part. i'm confused how can the result keep showing the random number.

i have tried to change the score++ to score=score+1 but no luck, is there any option for this problem?

i was writing my code as

```
 stop();

 
 var score:int=0;
 mulaitesButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startbtn3);
 function startbtn3(event:MouseEvent):void
 {
 gotoAndStop(13);
 }
```

and each frame containing :

```
stop();
optA.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextq11a);

function nextq11a(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    score++;
    gotoAndPlay(14);
}
optB.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextq11b);
stop();
function nextq11b(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    
    gotoAndPlay(14);
}

optC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextq11c);
stop();
function nextq11c(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    gotoAndPlay(14);
}
optD.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextq11d);
stop();
function nextq11d(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndPlay(14);
}
```

for plus 1 scorebut the result keep showing the wrong number as the code

```
stop();

skorHasil.text = score.toString();
```

please help

right showing number

Comment: I don't really see the problem with the script. I advise to **debug** the problem. Put a distinct **trace("A", score);** and **trace("B", score);** and so on commands after each key point. You are going to learn if your logic executes the way you expect it to, and the exact moment when **score** is not what it is supposed to be. That narrows down the problem and you just might understand where is the flaw.

Comment: hello, thanks for the answer, the main problem is the way I define each button with the same instance in each frame. the problem is solved!